# Install a new kernel: missing /lib/modules

Tags: kernel, compiling

Hi I have a problem to install the new kernel 5.15 on my machine. To install the new kernel, I do this :

- make menuconfig (I tried the cp .config method too) + modified lines to have no problem while the building (CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY="", CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="", CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS=""). Without this last step, I have some troubles with x509 certificates
- make
- sudo make install

When I do the last step, I have this :

```
mcarrere@silverstone:~/Téléchargements/linux-5.15$ sudo make install VERBOSE=1
arch/x86/Makefile:142: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 5.15.0 \
    arch/x86/boot/bzImage System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 5.15.0 /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 5.15.0 /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0                                                                                                                                                                                                               [ OK ] 
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 5.15.0 /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0
W: missing /lib/modules/5.15.0
W: Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/5.15.0: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
cat: /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_LbpZGW/lib/modules/5.15.0/modules.builtin: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p6
I: (UUID=281e04f6-0dcd-42cf-bde3-1b66a1c2f3b0)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.order at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_LbpZGW/lib/modules/5.15.0: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.builtin at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_LbpZGW/lib/modules/5.15.0: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 5.15.0 /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 5.15.0 /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/xx-update-initrd-links 5.15.0 /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 5.15.0 /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Création du fichier de configuration GRUB…
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.52
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.10.52
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.9.0-050900-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.9.0-050900-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-63-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-63-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.52
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.10.52
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.9.0-050900-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.9.0-050900-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-63-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-63-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.52
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.10.52
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.9.0-050900-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.9.0-050900-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-63-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-63-generic
Windows Boot Manager trouvé sur /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
CentOS Linux 7 (Core) trouvé sur /dev/nvme0n1p7
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.52
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.10.52
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.9.0-050900-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.9.0-050900-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-63-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-63-generic
Windows Boot Manager trouvé sur /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
CentOS Linux 7 (Core) trouvé sur /dev/nvme0n1p7
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
fait
```

I have no trouble while the "make".

What is the problem ? Is it usual to modify the .config for security keys ?

I need to install a kernel like this because I must modify the perf linux module and do some tests.

Thank you.

***EDIT1 :*** So it's work now. I followed this [topic](https://www.josehu.com/memo/2021/01/02/linux-kernel-build-debug.html) and without changing my previous .config, it's work but I don't understand why it's work. An idea ? It's very curious...

ps : I did some tests on different kernels before, no need for the moment to remove them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's ok with this [topic](https://www.josehu.com/memo/2021/01/02/linux-kernel-build-debug.html) :

```
$ sudo make menuconfig
change some lines in the .config :
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY=""
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS=""
CONFIG_SYSTEM_BLACKLIST_HASH_LIST=""
CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS=""
$ sudo make clean
$ sudo rm -rf debian
$ rm -f vmlinux-gdb.py
$ sudo make -j$(nproc) deb-pkg
$ cd ..
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb
$ awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " || $1=="submenu " {print i++ " : " $2}; /\tmenuentry / {print "\t" i-1">"j++ " : " $2};' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
$ sudo update-grub
```

Maybe It's not very clean for the encryption part but it's work. If someone has a better idea...